# "message": "invalid parameters: Access is denied", while sending json request to server -ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, afhttpclient

I'm posting a json to server, but I'm getting response  from server like this- 
 "message": "invalid parameters: Access is denied"

i sending request   like this-

```
AFHTTPClient * httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:json forKey:@"json"];

[httpClient postPath:@"/xxx/yyyy/zzzz" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"success parsing %@",responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"failure parsing  %@",error);
    }];
```

but i got response from server :

```
{
    "message": "invalid parameters: Access is denied",
    "data": null,
    "result": "false"
},
```

please give a good solution to fix this issue,  thanks

Comment: we know nothing about the service you try to connect to. so how should we able to tell you the right parameters? But at least a key `"json"` seems to be suspect to me.

Comment: First check API document and see what needs to be send for key json. Please refer to API Document.

Answer (score 0):

```
[httpClient postPath:@"hello" parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"data1", @"data1_key", @"data2", @"data2_key2", nil]
```